# Cocoa Change label title programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have a label bind with AppDelegate.  In AppDelegate, I have awakeFromNib() and I set label title to @"".  This works fine.

```
@synthesize statusMessage;

- (void)awakeFromNib {

    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.statusMessage = @""; // #0 This works fine.
}
```

In my push button action,

```
- (IBAction)openButton:(id)sender {

    self.statusMessage = @"";  // #1  Every button push, It works fine.

    ...

    // #2 This does not work at all
    NSString *processString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Processing %ld images",sortedURLsCount];
    self.statusMessage = NSLocalizedString(processString, @"Processing"); 

   ...

   #3 As end of button process, It works fine
   self.statusMessage = NSLocalizedString(@"Done", @"Done");

}
```

In summarize,

1. Label changes properly on application startup.
2. Label changes properly on every button push.
3. Label changes properly on end of button process.
4. But, When I try to change label to `*processString` in the start of process, it does not change at all.

I have tried **Continuously Update Value** option on xib's binding portion, but have not effect.
I also tried `NSNotificationCenter`.  **Notification** correctly passed to **selector** but even in this **selector**, I can't change label.

**NOTE:** My process is very short.  Mostly end within 20 secs.

How can I change label in the start of process?

Comment: Try to set the property on the main thread with `dispatch_async`

Comment: My process is not backgroundtask.

Comment: Have you made sure that processString is not nil?

Comment: @rocky Yes, I'm sure!

Comment: @vadian But You've give me a hint!  After I made my process to background task, `processString` was correctly displayed!  Thanks so much!